# Cannot modify hibernate settings

Tags: java, windows, hibernate

I created **hibernate.cfg.xml** and **UserDataFromDb.hbm.xml** and tried to put it in a correct place. First time there was exception like `"Cannot find hibernate.cfg.xml"`, but after several replacement correct place was found. New exception was (with except of lots of other trace):

> Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Enum class not found
>    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.codejava.hibernate.Gender

It is ok, because I've forgotten to change tutorial sample code and print my class name. I've fixed this problem, so, now there are no mentions about class Gender in **UserDataFromDb.hbm.xml**. Problem is certainly the same.

I've replaced both **UserDataFromDb.hbm.xml** and **hibernate.cfg.xml** to desktop and even renamed them. So, no there are no either **UserDataFromDb.hbm.xml** or **hibernate.cfg.xml** files on my computer (instead of them -- UserData11FromDb.hbm.xml and hiber111nate.cfg.xml on desktop). Exception are still the same:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Enum class not found
>    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.codejava.hibernate.Gender

though neither Gender class nor even configuration and mapping files exist on computer.

Rebooting computer makes no effect.
OS Windows 7, Hibernate 4.3.6

Config file:

`

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
            com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        </property>

        <!-- Assume test is the database name -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
            jdbc:mysql://localhost/abusefinder
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
            root
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">

        </property>

        <!-- List of XML mapping files -->
        <mapping resource="UserDataFromDb.hbm.xml" />

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd"> 

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="UserDataFromDb" table="user_history">
        <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <list name="operations" cascade="all">
            <key column="user_id"/>
            <list-index column="idx"/>
            <one-to-many class="Operation"/>
        </list>
        <property name="maxOpersPerWeek" column="max_opers_per_week" type="int"/>
        <property name="currentOpersPerWeek" column="current_opers_per_week" type="int"/>
        <property name="lastWeekFirstOperationTime" column="last_week_first_operation_time"     type="long"/>
        <property name="addTotal" column="add_total" type="long"/>
        <property name="getTotal" column="get_total" type="long"/>
        <property name="addOpers" column="add_opers" type="int"/>
        <property name="getOpers" column="get_opers" type="int"/>
    </class>


    <class name="Operation" table="operations">
        <id name="operId" type="int" column="oper_id">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <property name="userId" column="user_id" type="int"/>
        <property name="sum" column="sum" type="long"/>
        <property name="time" column="time" type="long"/>
        <property name="type" column="type">
            <type name="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">
                <param name="enumClass">databaseaccess.Type</param>
                <param name="useNamed">true</param>
            </type>
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: did you delete the jar file that may have been created after the build. repeated replacements may cause issues in the jar and the code that you replace may indeed have not been replaced after the build again.

Comment: I compile using eclipse run button. Where can i find jars?

Comment: Add your `hibernate.cfg.xml` and `UserDataFromDb.hbm.xml`. Is `net.codejava.hibernate.Gender` in the same jar with `hibernate.cfg.xml`?

Comment: There are no net.codejava.hibernate.Gender. Also there are no linking on it in actual mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Project -> clean
project -> build